# Can't build Virtualbox-dkms - mismatched kernel and headers

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 14.10

I have previously used VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine, but I had not used it in the last two months.

When I tried to start a VM, I got the following error:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

I found several other questions which say to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` or to uninstall and reinstall virtualbox.

When I run any of these commands, I get the following message:

```
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.3.18
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.18 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-29-generic
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                  [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
                                                                       [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

When I run `uname -a`, I see that the running Kernel version is `3.13.0-29-generic`, as the message above says.

However, when I check which Kernel headers are installed, I see these:

```
linux-headers-3.16.0-24 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-24-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-24-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-25 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-25-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-25-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-26 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-26-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-26-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-28 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-28-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-28-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-29 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-29-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-30 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-30-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-31 - Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.16.0
linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
linux-headers-3.16.0-31-lowlatency - Linux kernel headers for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I tried to install the `3.13.0-29` headers using `` sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` `` and got this error:

```
Package linux-headers-3.13.0-29-generic is not available...
```

I tried running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade the Kernel to `3.16...`, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I either update the installed kernel to match the headers that are available or get the old headers?

Comment: You may need to wait a few days for the kernel headers or, better, just use KVM (virt-manager). Same thing as Vbox, included in the kernel, no 3rd party apps. KVM + Spice FTW !!!

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I already have a lot of saved VMs in VirtualBox. Do you know of a tool to convert/import them to KVM?  Also, how well does KVM work with Vagrant? I've heard that there are a lot of issues.

Comment: KVM should use those disks just fine or you can convert them if you wish. Depends on what you want to convert them into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out after finding https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170580/package-linux-headers-3-13-0-27-generic-has-no-installation-candidate and noticing that 14.10 should have shipped with the `3.16` kernel from the start.

This machine was upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 using `do-release-upgrade`.  However, the `3.13.x` kernel from 14.04 was installed explicitly instead of through the `linux-image-generic` meta-package, so it didn't get upgraded.  However, the headers were installed using the `-generic` meta-package, so they did get updated.

Installing `linux-generic` caused the Kernel and Headers to both update to the newest `3.16.x`.